# Vba code to show selected data from combobox

Tags: vba, combobox

I have an Access 2010 form which has a combobox listing three columns:

1. ID
2. first name
3. last name

The combo box is bound to a table containing this data. The ID column in the combo box is hidden, it only shows the first and last name.

When the user selects a row only the the first name is shown. in the property section, I chose:

- Column Count: 3
- Column widths:0;3,3
- Bound Column: 1

I made another text field and in the combobox I wrote the following vbcode:

```
text=combo.value
```

that shows in the text field the chosen ID.

I want to show in another field (text\combo?) the last name.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

well I did it with recordset.
if someone know a simpler solution, I will be glad to lrn.
this is my code:

```
Dim dbs As ADODB.Connection
Dim id As String    

Set dbs = CurrentProject.AccessConnection 
Set rsRep = New ADODB.Recordset 
Set rsRep.ActiveConnection = dbs 

rsRep.Open "tblRep" 

id = Me.cbPrvFirstName
rsRep.MoveFirst
rsRep.Find "RepId=" & id

Me.txtPrvLastName = rsRep.Fields(2)
rsRep.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull in the value from another column within the combo box using the below code. By default `combo.value` will always give the value from the first column even if hidden.

try
`text=combo.column(x)`

in your case to retrieve `last name` it would be
`text=combo.column(2)`

> where x is a NUMBER of the column you want to retrieve 0 being the first column

You could also try an **alternative** - This works like a VLookup in excel if you are familiar with that.
(Not as simple as the first option ;) )

`text=Dlookup("[last name]","tblRep","RepId=" & combo.value)`